# create ajax autocomplete field like stackoverflow

Tags: ajax, autocomplete, mootools, jquery-autocomplete

How to create ajax autocomplete field,like Tags field in Stackoverflow that user can remove tag with remove icon after insert tags on fields.(with Mootools or jQuery)

Comment: what, like this: http://mootools.net/forge/p/mootagify

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Meio.Autocomplete Class to achieve this behaviour.
I am using it for exact the task you were asking for. Have a look at [this page](https://github.com/fabiomcosta/mootools-meio-autocomplete) for details on how to use it.